# NLB Target Group and Healthcheck Failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc-endpoint, aws-nlb

I am wanting to create a vpc endpoint service in order to provide a way for our internal apps to bypass our SSO page when calling JIRA.

Following this documentation: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/vpc/latest/privatelink/endpoint-service-overview.html

I create:

- NLB on Internal scheme (with Listener TLS on port 443)
- Target Group (TLS port 443)
- Health Check (TCP 443)
- Endpoint Service

My api node is listening on following ports:

```
root@ip-10-xx-xx-xx bin]# netstat -ltpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2632/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21588/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4070/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3180/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21588/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::40011                :::*                    LISTEN      21438/java
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      2632/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      21438/java
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      21588/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      4070/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::9080                 :::*                    LISTEN      21438/java
tcp6       0      0 :::40001                :::*                    LISTEN      21438/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      21438/java
```

---

My Target Instance and Healthcheck are constantly failing.

I have rebuilt the NLB/Target groups many times, trying TLS and TCP listener - but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: If it's internal app, why everything is https?

Comment: Good question.. Was just basing it on how it's already setup to go through oauth, and since port 443 was open, thought it would be an easy setup.